# Go : When will json.Unmarshal to struct return error?

Tags: json, go, struct

Assume i have a struct like

```
type A struct{
  name string`json:"name"`
}
```

Then in main i have code

```
var jsonString string = `{"status":false}`
var a A
error := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString),&a)
```

apparently the code above produce a nil error, regardless the json format is different. When will json.Unmarshal() return error in Go?

Comment: You want to make an example that works, or at least compiles, [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/ywOPSds8zQ). `Unmarshal` will return an error when the input is not valid JSON (like, change `false` to `hello`, or remove the close brace).

Comment: It's all open source, you can always check Unmarshal's implementation too: https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s=2621:2669#L64 (and checkValid: https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/scanner.go?s=732:781#L16)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The JSON decoder does not report an error if values in the source do not correspond to values in the target. For example, it's not an error if the source contains the field "status", but the target does not.

The Unmarshal function does return errors in other situations.

Syntax error

```
type A struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
data = []byte(`{"name":what?}`)
err = json.Unmarshal(data, &a)
fmt.Println(err)  // prints character 'w' looking for beginning of value
```

JSON value not representable by target type:

```
data := []byte(`{"name":false}`)
type B struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
}
var b B
err = json.Unmarshal(data, &b)
fmt.Println(err) // prints cannot unmarshal bool into Go value of type string
```

(This is one example of where the value cannot be represented by target type.  There are more.)

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/Z37o-Y9BVI)

Answer (score 13):

And more examples when `json.Unmarshal()` returns an error (besides specifying an invalid JSON):

Specifying a `nil` or `empty` slice:

```
i := 0
err := json.Unmarshal(nil, &i)
fmt.Println(err) // unexpected end of JSON input
```

Specifying a non-pointer to unmarshal into:

```
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"name":"a"}`), i)
fmt.Println(err) // json: Unmarshal(non-pointer int)
```

Specifying `nil` as the target pointer:

```
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"name":"a"}`), nil)
fmt.Println(err) // json: Unmarshal(nil)
```

Specifying JSON numbers that would overflow the target type. Quoting the doc of [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

> If a JSON value is not appropriate for a given target type, or if a JSON number overflows the target type, Unmarshal skips that field and completes the unmarshalling as best it can. If no more serious errors are encountered, Unmarshal returns an UnmarshalTypeError describing the earliest such error.

To demonstrate this:

```
var j int8
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`1112`), &j)
fmt.Println(err) // json: cannot unmarshal number 1112 into Go value of type int8
```

Or when trying to parse something as a `time.Time` which is not an RFC3339 timestamp:

```
var t time.Time
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`"xx"`), &t)
fmt.Println(err) // parsing time ""xx"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse "xx"" as "2006"
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to icza's answer, you can also get an error if you try to Unmarshal into a typed nil pointer. This can happen if, for example, you make a slice of pointers to a particular type, then try and unmarshal into a particular one of those pointers.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Example struct {Name string}


func main() {
        exs := make([]*Example, 5)
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"name":"jane"}`), exs[0])
        fmt.Println(err)
}
// json: Unmarshal(nil *main.Example)
```