# Can marshalling a map[string]string to json return an error?

Tags: json, dictionary, go, marshalling

Say I have the following code:

```
m := map[string]string{}
//... do stuff to the map
b, err := json.Marshal(m)
```

Is there any way in this case that the `json.Marshal` call would return an error?

I'm wondering partly out of curiosity and partly to consider whether I need to worry about that error check at all.

Comment: If a function returns an error value, you should check it, period.

Comment: Check it. Nothing much can go wrong with map[string]string but OOM could happen.

Comment: good point about OOM...

Comment: Error should always be checked if return by function whether it generates or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since any valid `string` value is a valid key and also a valid value in JSON (for details see [Which characters are valid/invalid in a JSON key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676011/which-characters-are-valid-invalid-in-a-json-key-name)), theoretically it won't return any errors.

If an out of memory error would occur, [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) would not return, your app would terminate with an error code.

Since Go stores `string` values as their UTF-8 encoded byte sequences, there is the question of invalid UTF-8 encoded string content. This also won't result in any errors, as Go will substitute invalid code points with the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD, like in this example:

```
m := map[string]string{"\xff": "a"}
data, err := json.Marshal(m)
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gQr7tZGXvfw)):

```
{"\ufffd":"a"} <nil>
```

This behavior is documented at `json.Marshal()`:

> String values encode as JSON strings coerced to valid UTF-8, replacing invalid bytes with the Unicode replacement rune.

It may be that marshaling a `map[string]string` will never return an error, still, you should always check returned errors unless the doc explicitly states that the returned `error` is always `nil` (the doc of `json.Marshal()` does not document such behavior). Such rare example is [`rand.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Read) which documents that *"it always returns len(p) and a nil error"*.

And there is also the possibility that the standard library has errors, so even though the implementation of the `json` package may not *intend* to return any error when marshaling a `map[string]string`, a bug may cause it to still return a non-`nil` error.

Also see related question: [Go : When will json.Unmarshal to struct return error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708717/go-when-will-json-unmarshal-to-struct-return-error/32709715#32709715)

#### Concurrent map modification

For completeness, let's discuss another issue that might cause `json.Marshal()` to fail when a `map[string]string` is passed to it.

[Go 1.6 added](https://golang.org/doc/go1.6#runtime) a lightweight concurrent misuse of maps detection to the runtime, you can read more about it here: [How to recover from concurrent map writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288741/how-to-recover-from-concurrent-map-writes/39289246#39289246)

This means that the Go runtime may detect if a map is read or modified in a goroutine, and it is also modified by another goroutine, concurrently, without synchronization.

So the scenario here is that we pass a `map[string]string` to `json.Marshal()`. And for it to be marshaled, the `json` package has to iterate over the key-values of the map obviously. If we modify the map concurrently, that will result in a fail.

Here is a sample code that provokes it (the loop is there to increase the likeliness of the concurrent modification, else we would be in the hands of the goroutine scheduler):

```
m := map[string]string{"\xff": "a"}

go func() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        m["x"] = "b"
    }
}()

for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
    if _, err := json.Marshal(m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Also note that in this case `json.Marshal()` will also not return (just like with the case of the out-of-memory error), instead the runtime will crash your app, intentionally. Output will be:

```
fatal error: concurrent map iteration and map write
```