# How to get an error while marshaling not json

Tags: go

I have a map whose key his string and value is an interface. I an putting some keys and values into that map I want to marshal it but I want to get a "nonvalid" or I want my marshal comes with an error? In order to succeed it, what kind of variables do I need to put into that map?

```
myBlobMap := make(map[string]interface{})
blobmap["firstKey"] = "firstValue"
blobmap["secondKey"] = "secondValue"
jsonByte, err := json.Marshal(myBlobMap)
```

Comment: Also related: [Can marshalling a map\[string\]string to json return an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239367/can-marshalling-a-mapstringstring-to-json-return-an-error/49240146#49240146)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Go documentation on json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/):

> Channel, complex, and function values cannot be encoded in JSON.
> Attempting to encode such a value causes Marshal to return an
> UnsupportedTypeError.
>
> JSON cannot represent cyclic data structures and Marshal does not
> handle them. Passing cyclic structures to Marshal will result in an
> error.

Here an example with a function that will return an error:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    myBlobMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    myBlobMap["firstKey"] = func() {}
    myBlobMap["secondKey"] = "secondValue"
    jsonByte, err := json.Marshal(myBlobMap)
    fmt.Print(jsonByte, err)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QmwbmEKqbwX)